# HAProxy balancing algorithm

Tags: webserver, haproxy

I have 4 servers for my search engine. I am using HAproxy for load balancing. Which balancing algorithm will be optimal to use in this case where request time will be small?

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the servers' strength. I mean if one server is more powerful than another, that it have to have more weight than the other. ;) I don't think that it depends on the work you're doing.;)

Comment: Thanks mtndesign,but what will the case where all servers are of same capacity?

Comment: Then I suggest you to use "source" or "leastconn" algorithm. According to the manual ,[link](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.3/doc/configuration.txt), source is going to hash the source IP and divide it into total weight of the servers and make sure that one IP is going to request the same server, as long asnothing changed. ;) And leastconn is going to measue which server have least connections, and will redirect the request to that server. Between these two, I would use "leastconn" ;)